# How can I edit the child of html node in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Don't know how to phrase this question but I need to modify the child of node :

```
<a id="page_number">1 / 1</a>
```

I'm using JS and JQuery. Up so far I get the node like this:

```
$("#page_number")[0]
```

Can I get this without have to use the square brackets (getElementById?). Then how to I modify the value '1 / 1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#page_number").html("this is the new content");
```

Comment: .html gets me the inner HTML?

Answer (score 1):

`$("#page_number")[0]` is giving you the raw dom node back from the jQuery object (by the way equivalent to `$("#page_number").get(0)` - note that I added the "#" in the selector which you need if you work with jQuery.

So you have two choices:

**Raw DOM**

```
//get
var myvar = document.getElementById("page_number").innerHTML;
//set
document.getElementById("page_number").innerHTML = "New Content";
```

**jQuery**

```
//get
$("#page_number").html();
//set
$("#page_number").html("New content");
```